# Draw in Preview

Tags: preview, big-sur, drawing

If I want to draw something in the Preview app, then for example odd lines become straight or something that resembles a circle becomes a circle. How can I turn this feature off?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be two quite similar icons for two different operations. You are describing 'Sketch' behavior. What you need is 'Draw' next to it.

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI... The **Draw** tool appears only on computers with a **Force Touch** trackpad.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing appears on the trackpad either.

Unfortunately, this option does not exist